# Auth0 - Use login_hint but do not auto submit passwordless form

Tags: auth0

We are using login_hint to populate a users email from local storage but the passwordless login form is auto submitting. Is there a way to continue to use login_hint without auto submitting a passwordless form to allow a user to modify their email address (if needed) and manually submit the form?

Comment: Update: I’ve tried a custom template and used this but still no joy, I have also tried to set the email input value by id, name etc etc:

var options = {
prefill: {
email: “someone@somewhere.com”
}
};